# how to use variable ranges in different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

I wrote a code for a product between 2 ranges. One of those ranges is in other and when i have tried to make it variable, appear some mistake. This is the code:

```
Sub Correlacionar()

Dim col As Integer
Dim random As Range
Dim SDesv As Range
Dim Chole As Range
col = 4

Set Chole = Sheet4.Range("a20:d23")
'Set Chole = Sheet4.Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(19 + col, col))

Set random = Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(3, 8 + col))
Set SDesv = Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(10, col))
SDesv = WorksheetFunction.MMult(random, WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Chole))
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I want to use:

```
Set Chole = Sheet4.Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(19 + col, col))
```

Instead of:

```
Set Chole = Sheet4.Range("a20:d23")
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Perhaps you can add some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set Chole = Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(20, 1), _
                         Sheet4.Cells(19 + col, col))
```

If you just use Cells then it will refer to the activesheet, not Sheet4.

It's good practice to *never* use either `Range` or `Cells` without a specific worksheet qualifier.  Your code should not depend on any specific sheet being active.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Can't work with ranges if workbook and sheet are not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861117/cant-work-with-ranges-if-workbook-and-sheet-are-not-active)

Cells implicitly refers to ActiveSheet.Cells

```
with sheet4
   set Chole = .range(.cells(20,1), cells(19 + cells(19 + col, col))
end with
```